# Classes and object in C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

i am trying to learn classes and objects in C#, i want to get the textbox value and show it in a label using classes and get set property.
i try the below process, but i will not showing/output anything.

**index.aspx code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="classes.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="lname" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Button Text="Submit" ID="submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Button click code**

```
 protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            basicinfo bn = new basicinfo();
            FirstName.Text = bn.fname;
        }
```

**class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace classes
{
    public class basicinfo
    {
        public string fname;
        public string last_name;
        public string password;
        public string Name
        {
            get{return fname;}
            set{fname=value;}
        }

    }

    }
```

Can someone tell me is this the wrong way?  Also please provide reference of any helping material/Links/video tutorials course through which i can clear my basic classes, get set, objects, methods idea, i am heaving trouble to understand it.

**Update**
if this how it works

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            basicinfo bn = new basicinfo();
            bn.Name = fname.Text;
            FirstName.Text =bn.Name;
        }
```

then why should we use classes and get, set properties?

we can simply do like

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FirstName.Text = fname.Text;
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest to try this one course: `https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/c-sharp-fundamentals-with-visual-studio-2015/table-of-contents` (I earn nothing by recommending them)

Comment: What text do you expect in the FirstName label?

Comment: i am trying to show the data in label using class and get, set property.

Comment: public string -> public static string

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the object value in the Label but Your object is empty it does not contain textbox value. Your code should be

```
 protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        basicinfo bn = new basicinfo();
        bn.fname= fname.Text; //textbox value to object
        FirstName.Text = bn.fname; //object value to label
    }
```

Comment: the code will fix the issue, but if this the the way to get it then why we should use classe and get set properties?
we can simple do it like `FirstName.Text =fname.Text; `